# Replace word from separated comma list

Tags: php, regex, string

My current code:

```
<?php

    $list = 'hello, sentence, banana, apple';
    $string = "This is a sentence";

    // output should be: This is a ****
    $output = str_replace($list, '****', $string);
    echo $output;

?>
```

Can anyone help me to output a string of text and replace words from a comma separated list please?

Comment: We are not a code writing service, have you tried anything ? Also you need to add more information what you want to replace with what.

Comment: I have tried using regex $message = str_replace($contents, '', preg_replace('/(?:#[\w-]+\s*)+$/', '', $string));

Comment: I didn't include that for the fear of embarrassment. I just don't understand regex

Comment: It's a swearing filter so if the string of text has a swear word it will replace with asterix's

Comment: ^ Include your attempts into your question. Also from this code I see a lot of unknowns. Please add more information, what you want to replace with what

Comment: I tried my best to edit it to make it more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your string into an array and then you can simply use it as you already did with [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). E.g.

```
$output = str_replace(array_map("trim", explode(",", $list)), '****', $string);
```

The `array_map()` call with `trim()` as callback, is just to remove all withespaces at the start and end of each array element.